# Is the System.gc() call in sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl a bad case?

Tags: java, java-8, garbage-collection

```java
try {
    // If no exception was thrown from map0, the address is valid
    addr = map0(imode, mapPosition, mapSize);
} catch (OutOfMemoryError x) {
    // An OutOfMemoryError may indicate that we've exhausted memory
    // so force gc and re-attempt map
    System.gc();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException y) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    try {
        addr = map0(imode, mapPosition, mapSize);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError y) {
        // After a second OOME, fail
        throw new IOException("Map failed", y);
    }
}
```

From [jdk/FileChannelImpl.java at jdk8-b120](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk8-b120/jdk/src/share/classes/sun/nio/ch/FileChannelImpl.java#L882).

Does this help with exception recovery?

Comment: In sone JRE's System.gc() is a no-op so it won't change a thing  if your JRE is one of them. It's also likely that the JRE already has been trying to do a gc before the exception is thrown.

Comment: This is a special case as the garbage collector does not track the native memory but the native buffer’s cleanup depends on the garbage collector detecting the unreachability of the frontend `ByteBuffer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an object allocation fails with an `OutOfMemoryError`, the garbage collector did already try its best to reclaim memory of unused objects or expanding the heap. So calling `System.gc()` after catching `OutOfMemoryError` would be pointless.

A special case is the situation when the garbage collector repeatedly did reclaim a tiny amount of memory, so the application could proceed, but have to perform another garbage collection right on the next allocation. Some garbage collectors throw an `OutOfMemoryError` with the message "GC Overhead Limit Exceeded" when they detect that the application spent more than 98% of the CPU time for garbage collection. In this situation, calling `System.gc()` would be counter productive, as then, the application spends even more time in garbage collection plus creating and processing `OutOfMemoryError`s.

---

The `FileChannelImpl`’s case is different. `map0` may fail due to insufficient native memory or, in case of 32 bit systems, when running out of address space. In these cases, the heap memory manager did not produce the `OutOfMemoryError` and it is possible that the garbage collector didn’t run. But to reclaim native memory or address space, the associated `ByteBuffer` instances must get garbage collected, so their cleaner can run. This is a rare corner case where calling `System.gc();` makes sense.

It’s still fragile, as `System.gc();` is not guaranteed to collect all objects or to run the garbage collector at all. [JEP 383](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/383) is supposed to solve this, by providing better control over the lifetime of native allocations.

Comment: I've heard a very good talk from Pangin, where he detailed the fact that currently there is no other way to release native memory, besides calling `System.gc` when such cases occur. That was the moment we started to _not_ disable explicit gc VM option.

Answer (score 2):

In the give example, the problem is insufficient memory. Thus, running the garbage collector to free up memory might remedy this. But the call to [`System.gc()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#gc()) is only a suggestion to the JVM. It is not guaranteed that that the garbage collector frees any memory through this call.

So this approach is somewhat of a heuristic.